# Probability question dealing with conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An urn contains one red chip and one white chip.
One chip is drawn at random. If the chip selected is red,
that chip together with two additional red chips are put
back into the urn. If a white chip is drawn, the chip is
returned to the urn. Then a second chip is drawn. What
is the probability that both selections are red?

The answer I keep obtaining is 2/3 but the actual textbook answer is 3/8.

Comment: Sounds like homework, so I won't give a full solution.  First, does it make sense that your answer is more than 1/2?  Think about just the first draw, it is a 1/2 chance that the first chip is red.  So, we want the probability that draw 1 is red AND draw 2 is red.  What does the word 'and" mean for probabilities?

Comment: How did you get $2/3$?  If you tell us that, we might be able to tell you where your mistake is. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

In order to draw two red chips, you must draw the red chip the first time; this happens with probability $\frac12$. If you do draw the red chip initially, the second draw is from an urn with three red chips and one white chip, so the probability of drawing a second red chip is $\frac34$. Thus, the probability of drawing two red chips is $\frac12\cdot\frac34=\frac38$.

Note that a quick sanity check can tell you that $\frac23$ is impossible: the probability *cannot* be greater than the probability of drawing a red chip the first time, which is clearly $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\Pr(\text{1st is red & 2nd is red)} = \Pr(\text{1st is red})\cdot\Pr(\text{2nd is red} \mid \text{1st is red}) = \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 3 4.
$$